# Why angular directives are not working when added programmatically

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Can some body explain me why below directive is not getting called? Its getting called if I directly add the directive to the button. I tried it adding using $timeout but still no luck.

```
<html>      
       <head>
          <title>AngularJS</title>
          <script src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>

          <script type="text/javascript">

          var app = angular.module('MyApp',[]);

          app.controller('MyCtrl',function($scope,$timeout){

          document.getElementById('myBtn').setAttribute('my-directive','');

          });

          app.directive('myDirecitive',function(){

             function linkFn (scope,element,attrs){
                element.bind('click',function(){
                   alert('Clicked');
                });         
             }

             return {
                restrict:'A',
                link:linkFn
             }
          });         

          </script>

       </head>

       <body ng-app="MyApp", ng-controller="MyCtrl">       
          <button id="myBtn">Test</button>           
       </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: directive name spelled wrong

Comment: Just a guess but you'll probably want to read up on [$scope.$apply()](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$apply).

Comment: @adamdport I tried doing it $apply. Still it does not work.

Comment: Then you'll have to run `$compile` on it manually.

Answer (score 1):

```
 app.directive('myDirecitive',function(){
```

should be

```
app.directive('myDirective',function(){
```

it's best not to query the DOM inside the controller. Don't do this

```
document.getElementById('myBtn').setAttribute('my-directive','');
```

`my-directive` was created as an attribute directive, so it would be best to add that directly to the element like this.

```
<button id="myBtn" my-directive>Test</button>
```

I created a plunker

https://plnkr.co/edit/pispsMzbJIxrIDyIv81N?p=preview

Comment: Thanks.. It was a typo.. But still it does not work. Did you try it?

Comment: Yap. Thanks. Its working if you add it directly as I have mentioned in the question. But if i add it using java script, this does not work.

Comment: Using `setAttribute`? You're not supposed to use it. That's a bad practice.

Comment: I have a requirement where the part of the dom is getting rendered with a delay. What I intended to do was, adding a directives dynamically with a timeout once that particular part of dom is completely rendered. Can you suggest me a solution?

Comment: The angular solution is to use `ng-if="delayComplete"` on the part of the dom you don't want rendered, and toggle `delayComplete` in your `$timeout`